# Netbeans with xdebug not highlighting debugged lines

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I finally managed to get xdebug working but now I am facing a strange problem. I can see the variables, I can step through the code but i can't see what line I'm actually debugging. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't see highlighted lines, it's possible that the project settings aren't configured correctly.

E.g. when using a htaccess redirect from the root folder to folder myapplication, be sure to edit Project->Properties->Sources->Web Root to the redirect folder.

That solved the issue for me.

Comment: This just was a huge help!

Comment: This worked for me as well. Should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Under Netbeans > Project Properties > Sources, be sure that the Web Root is set right to refer to the directory where the running page is. This could be one of the possible reasons of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue, and it was because I did not set up Path Mapping in the project.

Project -> Run Configuration -> Advanced

More info here: https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/path_mapping_in_php_debugger

Answer (score 1):

In my case what seems to have fixed the problem is to right click the file (in my case a java file) choose "select in projects" then it asked me if I want to open the project (actually this is what I think was happening, I had the file opened but not the project), I said yes and then netbeans started to show me the line as it goes debugging.